# How can I identify this hash?

Tags: hash

I'm trying to decrypt my router's root password, since I only have access to a simple admin account that doesn't have root privileges. Here is the passwd file:

```
0:F.bCrWv/Oxp6.:0:0:root:/home:/bin/sh
nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:/sbin/nologin
derp:heooPbcMgdldo:0:0:ftp user:/mnt:/bin/sh
```

I only want the identification of the first hash only. The purpose I want root in my router for is to setup a TFTP server to upload a new filesystem to my router and the reflash it into the router. If you could also provide me a method so that I crack the hash after identifying it, that would be great.

Comment: If this is your router, you should not have to decipher the root password to get full privileges. Moreover, as you say, the password is not encrypted but hashed. The difference is that a hash function is not reversible. So you can't get the original data from the hash, unless you find the correspondence in a dictionary

Comment: i clearly stated that i want help to crack the encrypted string or hash (as you want to call it) in the lower side of the question. and by that I MEANT THAT I WANTED TO USE DICTIONARY ATTACKS!

Comment: I think the best way to get the hash function is to look for "[linux distribution] passwd hash algorithm" on your favorite search engine. Then good luck to find a dictionary containing this specific hash. If I were you, I would RTFM either to get the root password or to get the way to change it. If this is not possible, the vendor might have a good reason. PS: Basically, uppercase letters are not meant to shout out aggressively.

Comment: I ran your `root` password through the `john` utility. I am not using that utility often, so I had a bit of trouble figuring out what arguments to give it. Eventually I realized my problem was that the password was so obvious, that I didn't even recognize it as a password in the output from `john`, but the password was there on my screen the entire time. This password is so easy to break, one wouldn't even need using a sophisticated tool like `john`. How many password candidates did you try by hand before asking here? My guess is: less than the number of words in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the vendors documentation hasn't turned up anything (which is where I'd start looking), you could use a tool like [Hash Identifier](https://code.google.com/p/hash-identifier/) to give you an idea of what this might be.  Once you've identified the algorithm then it's a question of finding a tool which supports cracking that.  Likely candidates are [John](http://www.openwall.com/john/) or [hashcat](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain that's a classic DES-based `crypt()` hash.  It's the right length (13 characters), the right character set ([A-Za-z0-9/.]), and the absence of a hash indicator at the beginning (`$1$`, etc.) would point to this style of hash.  John the Ripper is capable of attacking it, either via brute force or dictionary attacks, and it's worth noting that only the first 8 characters are significant, so your password is probably less than or equal to 8 characters.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that it's DES. now i have to find the key for decrypting the hash. how can i find the key? also can i find the key if i know the original password behind the hash of "derp" (derp:heooPbcMgdldo:0:0:ftp user:/mnt:/bin/sh)?

Comment: If you know the password, if `crypt('pass', 'heooPbcMgdldo')` equals `'heooPbcMgdldo'`, then it's the right password.